# кто знает как сделать такие же сообщения python telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

кто знает как сделать такие же сообщения python telebot
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это всплывающее уведомление после какого-нибудь действия, или оно постоянно в чате висит?

Answer (score 1):

уже нашел

```
bot.answer_callback_query(call.id,'ваш текст')
```